# top-bar button bad css positioning float right

Tags: css

I have a bar with a title on the left and  buttons inline on the right, the buttons can be one, two or three added dinamically, and can be or link syled like a button or input button, if you see this code with firefox the buttons are overlapping, with chrome and explorer buttons alignment is wrong

CSS:

```
html, body {
height : 99%;
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size : 85%;
color : #333399;
}
h2 {
font-size : 170%;
margin : 0;
color : #333399;
}
#title {
position : relative;
width : 70%;
background-color : #BAB3D6;
padding : 10px 0 10px 16px;
margin-left : auto;
margin-right : auto;
margin-bottom : 3px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
#title a{
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
#title div {
float : right;
margin-top : -22px;
margin-right : 30px;
}
.button {
 background-color : #333399;
 border : 0;
 padding : 6px 20px;
 text-decoration : none;
  color : white;
cursor : pointer;
 border-radius : 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 }
 .button:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  position : relative;
  top : 1px;
   }
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="title">
 <h2>title</h2>
 <div class="button"><a href="#">add</a></div>
 <div class="button"><a href="#">edit</a></div>
 <div ><input class="button" type="submit" name="delete_button" value="delete" />
 </div>
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zL4P6/

Comment: "buttons alignment is wrong" is not helpful. you need to explain both what is happening AND what you want to happen instead. Instead of reposting your code above, I suggest photoshopping an image that shows what you want.

Comment: maybe if you see the jsfiddle with different browser you know what I want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your HTML markup at some aspect to achieve whatever you want. See i've implemented the desired layout. Hope it will help you

**HTML**

```
<div id="title">
    <h2>title</h2>
    <div class="buttons"> <!-- wrapped the html into one div -->
        <div class="button"><a href="#">add</a>
        </div>

        <div class="button"><a href="#">edit</a>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input class="button" type="submit" name="delete_button" value="delete" />
        </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div> // Added clearfix to floats
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 99 %;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font - family: Arial, Helvetica, sans - serif;
    font - size: 85 %;
    color: #333399;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 170%;
    margin: 0;
    color: # 333399;
    float: left; /* New property added */
}

#title {
    position: relative;
    width: 70 %;
    background - color: #BAB3D6;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 16px;
    margin - left: auto;
    margin - right: auto;
    margin - bottom: 3px;
    - moz - border - radius - topleft: 10px;
    - webkit - border - top - left - radius: 10px;
    border - top - left - radius: 10px;
    - moz - border - radius - topright: 10px;
    - webkit - border - top - right - radius: 10px;
    border - top - right - radius: 10px;
}

    #title a {
        color: white;
        text - decoration: none;
    }

.buttons { /*  New class added */
    float: right;
}

    .buttons div {
        display: inline - block;
    }

.button {
    background - color: #333399;
    border: 0;
    padding: 6px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
}

    .button:active {
        text-decoration: none;
        position: relative;
        top: 1px;
    }

.clear { /* new class added */
    clear: both;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zL4P6/1/)

See i have mentioned changes with comments in above code

Answer (score 0):

There is a much cleaner, more logical way of implementing this, please see the below HTML/CSS.

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HTWsJ/2/)

HTML

```
<div>Title
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Delete</a></li>
        <li><button>Edit</button></li>
            <li><input type='submit' value='Add'/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
div {
    background:#BAB3D6;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    padding:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#333399;
    font-family:arial;
}
ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:300px;
}
ul li a, ul li button, ul li input[type=submit]{
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:none;
    border:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    line-height:15px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    color:white;
    font-size:12px;
    background:#333399;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:5px 10px;
    margin:0 5px;
}
```

Comment: the buttons can be link button styled but also input type